# Using GPL v3 for GitHub repo with no source code

Tags: gpl-3, github

I am planning to create a GitHub repo containing a summary of commands to be used as a reference. Some of these commands with a combination of unique flags have been used in the source code of a GitHub project that uses GPL v3, which informed my repo. The command reference I am creating has some commands that are based on this repo. Can I still use GPL v3 even though my repo does not contain source code or is there a more relevant license for my case?

Comment: In such cases a CC is usually used. However nothing prevents you from using GPL for that.

Answer (score 5):

The GPL defines the term Source Code as "the preferred format for making changes". This means that if your repository just contains some documentation files in a readily editable format (text, markdown, OpenOffice, MS Word, etc.) then those files count as their own source format.

Comment: So does this mean that GPL v3 would be an appropriate license to use in my case?

Comment: @synthesis, yes.